# How can I center the text because it appears to the edge of border-right

Tags: html, css

```
nav ul li {
    width: 155px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
}

nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    font-size: 13px;
    height:19px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
```

How can I center the text because comes to the edge of `border-right`?
As you can see, I couldn't center the text with `text-align`.

Comment: Can you add your html? and possibly put it  in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have good code. I believe you need to add the following code to your `nav ul a` CSS rule:

```
 nav ul a {
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

This should fix the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

on guess solution is:
you can do it by adding padding like
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

can you post any link please where we can check it ?

Comment: if solve issue accept as a answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you add too much these margin,padding things.**Get rid of margin-left on anchor** and **text-align:center** is going to work.
Good luck!